# How do I find the attribute to two separate words in Python?

Tags: python, random

I need to select, at random, two different words and then get the value which is linked to both of them. Let me explain, further:

The first list would be `"masculine, feminine, neuter, plural"` and the second would be `"nom, acc, gen, dat"`.

I want the program to select one from each at random, and then have the user provide the option. So, if it selected masc + nom, the user should answer (through an `input` option) der. When they do, I want to tell them if they're right or wrong.

I hope this makes sense.

How would you implement this? I can select the words at random just fine, but I'm just not sure about how to find the answer.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What does `der` mean? I don't understand how it's linked to "masc" and "nom".

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using an analogy or something but I thought that might make it more confusing. It's from German. German's have 16 words for 'the', and it comes from [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_articles). Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: well... 16 cases, but only 6 distinct words :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's clearly what I meant. I think the use of the word "word" is perfectly acceptable and makes an understandable amount of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# list labels for columns
columns = ['Masculine', 'Neuter', 'Feminine', 'Plural']

# list labels for rows
rows = ['Nominative', 'Accusative', 'Dative', 'Genitive']

# create a grid of answers for combination of column-rows
answers = [['der', 'das', 'die', 'die'],
        ['den', 'das', 'die', 'die'],
        ['dem', 'dem', 'der', 'den'],
        ['des', 'des', 'der', 'der']]

def correct_answer(column_name, row_name):
    # get correct indexes
    column_index = columns.index(column_name)
    row_index = rows.index(row_name)
    # used indexes to get answer
    return answers[row_index][column_index]

print correct_answer('Masculine', 'Accusative')
```

output:

```
den
```

Comment: I ended up using this answer, as it seemed the easiest to build into my question's requirements of the random element and user input. With just a few extra lines of code, it's all working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need some sort of *table* of correct answers.

If you make a table like this:

```
[["der","die","das","die"],
 ["den","die","das","die"],
 ["dem","der","dem","den"],
 ["des","der","des","der"]]
```

You can look the entries up by index like so:

```
mfnp = "masculine, feminine, neuter, plural".split(',')
nadg = "nom, acc, gen, dat".split(',')

s1 = "masculine"
s2 = "acc"
print table[mnfp.index(s1)][nadg.index(s2)]
```

#### Using a dictionary:

Alternatively, you could put all the entries in a dictionary:

```
d = {}
d["masculine"]["nom"] = "der"
d["masculine"]["acc"] = "den"
#...
d["neuter"]["gen"] = "dem"
#etcetera
```

Comment: You might want to swap rows 3 and 4 in the table to make it grammatically correct ("dem der dem..." is for "dat", and "des der des..." is for "gen").

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of words and their properties, these are your answers you campare the input against:

```
list1 = ["masc", "fem"]
list2 = ["dom", "gen"]
answers = {"word1": ["masc", "nom"], "word2": ["fem", "gen"], ...}

prop1 = random.choice(list1)
prop2 = random.choice(list2)
answer = input_from_user(prop1, prop2)
if prop1 in answers[answer] and prop2 in answers[answer]:
    print "correct"
else:
    print "incorrect"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will randomly pull out a string from your lists

```
from random import *

list1 = ['masculine', 'feminine', 'neuter','plural']
list2 = ['nom','acc','gen','dat']

var1 = random.sample(list1,1)
var2 = random.sample(list2,1)

var3 = str(var1) + '+' + str(var2)
```